# Opengl: issue with masking

Tags: opengl, masking, blending

I'm working on creating a hole in a wall using masking in opengl, my code is quit simple like this,

```
//Draw the mask
glEnable(GL_BLEND);                         
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR,GL_ZERO);  
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex3f(-20,40,-20);
glTexCoord2d(0,1);glVertex3f(-20,40,40);
glTexCoord2d(1,1);glVertex3f(20,40,40);
glTexCoord2d(1,0);glVertex3f(20,40,-20);

glEnd();

//Draw the Texture
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);


glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex3f(-20,40,-20);
glTexCoord2d(0,1);glVertex3f(-20,40,40);    
glTexCoord2d(1,1);glVertex3f(20,40,40);
glTexCoord2d(1,0);glVertex3f(20,40,-20);
glEnd();
```

The problem is, I got the hole in the wall correctly but it's semi transparent, I'm getting like black shade over it, also I can see through it.
Here's a photo for what I'm getting:
[image]

any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED :D**
It was a problem with the surfaces' Normals, once I set the normals in the correct position.The black shade faded out.